# Photos not deleting off iPad when deleted from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

When I take a pic on my iPhone it syncs to my iPad as well, but when I delete a pic from my iPhone, it doesn't get deleted off my iPad.

iOS 8.1, 
iPhone 5c,
iPad Air

The following settings are enabled:

Settings > iCloud > Photos > My Photo Stream and Photo sharing

Settings > Photos and Camera > My Photo Stream and Photo sharing on the iPhone

Settings > Photos and Camera > My Photo Stream and Photo sharing on the iPad

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Where are you deleting the picture from, Camera Roll or Photo Stream? Deleting from Camera Roll does not remove a picture from other devices. Deleting from Photo Stream should.

Answer (score -1):

My opinion that you had better make format to your ipod.I don't know exactly whether will be ok or not.you do as well.